# Como adicionar o caminho de uma âncora no endereço da página

Tags: javascript, html

Criei uma onepage, usei âncoras e id para fazer a navegação interna. Preciso que ao final da url do site seja mostrado qual parte do site está sendo exibida.

Exemplo:
Ao acessar o site essa url é carregada:
[www.meusite.com/index.html](http://www.meusite.com/index.html)

Ao clicar no link "contato", preciso que isso seja incrementado no endereço, ficando assim:
[www.meusite.com/index.html#contato](http://www.meusite.com/index.html#contato)

Estou usando

```
<a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contato">Contato</a>

<section class="page-section contato" id="contato">
```

Comment: Parece estar correto. Qual problema esta tendo?

Comment: Preciso que o id seja adicionado ao endereço da página, mas quando clico em qualquer link âncora, o endereço do site permanece o mesmo. Quando clico em "contato" o endereço do site segue sendo "dominio.com/index.html" e preciso que fique "dominio.com/index.html#contato"

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu preciso, mas aqui não muda.

Comment: Consegui resolver, removi a classe js-scroll-trigger.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, é apenas um site teste para fazer alguns tagueamentos através do GTM, do jeito que está já consigo capturar o que eu precisava. Esse js-scroll-trigge é um script para suavizar a rolagem da página, no momento não preciso disso, se for o caso altero o js.